# getdate() ошибка

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите где ошибся, нужно от даты отнять 1 день

```
var edate = "2018-12-26";
var ddd =  new Date(edate)
const dayMilliseconds = 24*60*60*1000;
var pp = new Date(ddd.setTime(ddd.getTime() - dayMilliseconds));
alert(pp.getFullYear()+'-'+pp.getMonth()+'-'+pp.getDay());
```

в итоге выводит 2018-11-1

Comment: `getDate` вместо `getDay` ))

Answer (score 1):

Что мешает воспользоваться библиотекой [moment](https://momentjs.com/).

Достаточно строчки кода:

```
moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar();
```